# Select n cells from a raster maximizing their variance

Tags: raster, r, algorithm

I work in R, especially using 'raster' package. It is a computational problem too hard for my syntax capacities.

STEP 1.
I have a one band raster, and what I want to select is a set of n cells (in my case, n = 15) as different as possible different regarding their values. In mathematical terms, in my selection I want to maximize the variance of values. Obviously, there are a huge amounts of combinations, but I would select the best one solution.

STEP 2. 
One further methodological complication is that at the same time I would like to maximize the distance between cells. I mean, once reached a set of possibilities from step1 (variance optimization), I would like to select the best solution in terms distance between cells (for example, the sum of distance between cells).

Is it possible? (at least the step1, but preferentially also step2)

Comment: Step 1 on its own has a single optimum answer, at which point step 2 doesn't make any sense. If you can specify how you want to trade off size of variance against separation distance then you can feed an optimiser and get an answer. But variance of values and distance sum aren't on the same scale...

Comment: If I want to obtain only step 1 what can I do? Concerning step2, I simple want to avoid a selection of cells in which cells are too close each one, but on the contrary a set of cells as widespread as possible throughout the raster. I'm aware about non specifity of the second question.... but I'm opened to suggestion and/or proposals in this regard.

Comment: I think by constructing a vector Y by sequentially picking values from X that have the biggest squared difference from the mean of the current values in Y you end up with a maximal variance set Y from X. I have code but no proof...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If you are able to share the code, I can test it applied to my cases and give you a feedback about the results.

Comment: There's an algorithm in the comment from @whuber here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24771/k-subset-with-maximal-variance#comment45156_24771 - it seems evidently correct and not evidently the same as my algorithm....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertion: This function picks `m` values from `x` that maximise the variance in the result:

```
maxvar <- function(x,m){
    y = picks = rep(NA, m)
    my = mean(x)
    for(i in 1:m){
        furthest = which.max((x-my)^2)
        picks[i] = furthest
        y[i] = x[furthest]
        x[furthest]=NA
        my = mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)
    }
    data.frame(i=picks,y=y)
}
```

Example:

Lets make a skewed data set:

```
> set.seed(123)
> z8 = sort(runif(100)^8)
```

And pick the 13 values that maximise the variance:

```
> z8m = maxvar(z8, 13)
> z8m
     i            y
1  100 9.550671e-01
2    1 2.321560e-26
3    2 1.347141e-13
4   99 8.858049e-01
5    3 9.792997e-12
6   98 7.397717e-01
7    4 1.855251e-11
8    5 1.946647e-11
9   97 7.025713e-01
10   6 5.888717e-09
11  96 6.890024e-01
12   7 6.545707e-09
13   8 1.253514e-08
```

The `i` column tells you where in the vector the value came from, and since `z8` was sorted you can see that it picked 8 from the low values and 5 from the high values.

The variance is then:

```
> var(z8m$y)
[1] 0.1665554
```

As a check we can manually compute the variance by subscripting by the values in the column:

```
> var(z8[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,96,97,98,99,100)])
[1] 0.1665554
```

Now suppose we took 9 values from the low end, and four from the top end instead - do we get a higher variance?

```
> var(z8[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,97,98,99,100)])
[1] 0.15904
```

Nope. How about 7 values from the low end and 6 from the top?

```
> var(z8[c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,95,96,97,98,99,100)])
[1] 0.1641997
```

nope, that's lower too. Similar exercises seem to make it clear this code does return the optimum. I'm pretty sure there's a proof that this is the variance-maximising sample. I'll ask my statistician colleagues...

Let's apply this to Zinc measurements at the points in the `meuse` data set.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y
max_var_zinc = maxvar(meuse$zinc, 15)
head(max_var_zinc)
#     i    y
# 1  54 1839
# 2 107  113
# 3 106  117
```

Gives us a sample variance of:

```
var(max_var_zinc$y)
# [1] 568741.5
```

And has selected these red points:

[image]

```
plot(meuse)
plot(meuse[max_var_zinc$i,],col="red",add=TRUE,pch=19)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems promising. I'll wait about your colleagues' opinion. In order to fully match my aims, and to produce a reliable example for all users, could you kindly calibrate the code on the dataset "meuse" from raster package? The final output should be a dataframe with n selected cells holding three columns ("x", "y", "zinc"), where the factor "zinc" is that on which the function above have to be applied [instead, "x" and "y" are the coordinates, which are fundamental to me to localize the cells selected by your function]

Comment: There's no `meuse` in the raster package and the one in `sp` is a data frame and not a raster.

Comment: You are right concerning meuse, sorry. Your code now fully satisfies my aims. Thank you!